# Book where futuristic artefacts appear from a reactor breach. One allows time travel 80 years into the future, where everyone is gone!

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

I read this around 5 or more years ago. The cover art was a shattered Statue of Liberty. It was set in current times.

This book has artefacts that appear from a reactor breach. They are futuristic devices. One allows time travel to 80 years in future where everyone is dead. Apparently, satellites emit waves driving everyone crazy.

There's one memorable scene where everyone is cornered in an area of the desert, where the satellite broadcast allows them to congregate. All die and bones are part of the scenery. People from past arrive and there is a conflict and cars light up in a huge conflagration.

Other artefacts were replicator machines.

Comment: When did you read this?  Was it a paperback, hardcover or e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: Around 5 or more years ago. Cover art was shattered Statue of Liberty. Other artefacts were replicator machines. Set in current time. One memorable scene where everyone is cornered in an area of the desert where the satellite broadcast allows them to congregate. All die and bones part of scenery. People from past arrive and there is a conflict and cars lights up in huge conflagration.

Comment: "satellites emit waves driving everyone crazy" -- what, like TV broadcasts? :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is ***[Ghost Country](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8479092-ghost-country)*** (2010) by Patrick Lee, the second book in the *[Travis Chase](https://www.goodreads.com/series/60963-travis-chase)* trilogy.

- Book 1: *[The Breach](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6987527-the-breach)* (2009)
- Book 2: *Ghost Country* (2010)
- Book 3: *[Deep Sky](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12135086-deep-sky)* (2011)

[image: Front cover of "Ghost Country" (2010) by Patrick Lee.]

According to [this review](https://pulpfictionreviews.blogspot.com/2013/02/the-breach-trilogy-by-patrick-lee.html) of the trilogy, a particle collider test conducted in 1978 opened a wormhole to an unknown place or time, through which various objects -- dubbed 'Breach entities' -- have subsequently appeared; some mundane, others unfathomable and even dangerous.

> **Tangent agents are trusted to guard, examine and study, The Breach, which is a form of wormhole that resulted when a particle collider was tested back in 1978. Since that time, items have been appearing on our side of the breach, items sometimes mundane, often unfathomable, and often deadly dangerous with strange properties and powers. Are they from the future? Another dimension? Are they the prelude to alien invasion? No one knows. Called Brach Entities, the good guys need to keep these items away from the bad guys.**

According to the same review, the plot of *Ghost Country* involves a Breach entity that permits travel 73 years into the future, where where mankind has been wiped out.

> Campbell, with mere seconds before capture, must get a message to Chase telling him to retrieve a Breach Entity similar to the one lost in the destroyed motorcade. Chase, who has left Tangent and Campbell for compelling reasons set down in the first novel, has no choice but to re-involve himself with Tangent and the Breach and sets out to find this second artifact.
>
> **This device turns out to be a means for the user to jump ahead 73 years into the future - a future where mankind has been wiped out by a Breach entity.**

This [user review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1138577833) of *Ghost Country* notes that the protagonists visit a desert town where they find mummified bodies everywhere, with thousands of cars from all over the US parked in the desert, and that the deaths were the result of a brain altering satellite.

> In another scene the characters go 70 years into the future and see mummified bodies everywhere in a desert town.
>
> [...]
>
> They also find hundreds of thousands of cars from all across America parked in neat, orderly rows in the desert. **Even if the people were under the effects of a brain altering satellite (as the reader discovers later on in the story) this premise is ludicrous.**

Comment: Thank you so much! You are amazing!